# Best way to embedd the PHP variables java in .js files

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

i have JavaScript files that are included at the top of the page and their content is generated by the `php` script.
we can echo the `php` variables easily in the `.php` extension files but what will be the best solution for `.js` files?
Either convert the data to `json` and store that in the file and pass to the script or any other better and efficient approach available?

Comment: You can mention header as header("content-type: application/javascript"); in php file and include this php file as a script src..

Answer (score -2):

Use Smarty Template engine. You can access PHP variables in JS file like following:

// Code goes here

PHP file:

```
<?php
$smarty->assign("Name", "PHP");
?>
```

HTML file or JS file

```
<script>
var php_var = {/literal}{$Name}{literal};
</script>
```

Comment: Are you going to include that external js file into any HTML files or not?

Comment: OK, Follow these steps
1. Assign php variable as smarty variable in back-end php of main HTML file.Refer above php script for variable assign.

2. Access that smarty variable in your external  .js file. Refer above code for variable  access in js.

3. Then, include .js file into main HTML file and that's it. Assigned php variable is available in js now.